# SonarQube analysis is failing after upgrade from 6.2 to 6.3.1

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan

After upgrading SonarQube from 6.2 to 6.3.1 the analysis is failing with this error:

```
10:31:45.361 ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources for .....:F97737D2-1926-4521-A9F0-4093946864AA
10:31:45.363 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:31:45.363 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
10:31:45.363 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:31:45.363 INFO: Total time: 6.466s
10:31:45.418 INFO: Final Memory: 50M/285M
10:31:45.418 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:31:45.418 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:70)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:273)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:112)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:70)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:68)
... 23 more
Caused by: The folder 'C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\5\s\....\Q_SAMPLE' does not exist for '.....:F97737D2-1926-4521-A9F0-4093946864AA' (base directory = C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\5\s\.....)
10:31:45.422 ERROR:
10:31:45.422 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I'm using the following configuration:

- SonarQube server v6.3.1
- SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild v2.1.0 (task
  for TFS build)
- Oracle Database 12c

I checked the folder that is reported as not existing in the log (..Q_SAMPLE) and I found that it is not actually a folder but an XML file called Q_SAMPLE$0.xml. My suspect is that the scanner is interpreting the file name as a folder because of the character '$' in the file name, even if this is a valid Windows file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a bug that we are about to fix: [SONARMSBRU-322](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-322).